# jquery function is only working in the console

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I have a script that is supposed to wait for dom loaded to fire but it doesn't seem to wait.
I think the problem might be that I am using bootstrap tabs and the content isn't really in the dom yet.

It works however if I paste the jQuery into the console. Is there a way to fix this with jQuery or do I need a powerful ajax library?

html/bootstrap

```
 /*@include('blocks.rotators.user-comments') loads in this*/

 <div class="tab-pane fade" id="activityDetails">
   <div class="comments-holder holder"></div>

  <!-- item container -->
   <ul id="comments-container" class="default-container quad-scroller">
       <li>item</li>
   </ul>    
</div>
```

JS

```
/* when document is ready */
    $(function () {
            /*
             * initiate the plugin without buttons and numeration
             * setting midRange to 15 to prevent the breaks "..."
             */
            $("div.comments-holder").jPages({
                    containerID: "comments-container",
                    first: false,
                    previous: "←",
                    next: "→",
                    last: false,
                    midRange: 15,
                    perPage: 4,
                    links: "blank"
            });
    });
```

Comment: How is the HTML you've posted added to the DOM? Are you sure DOM ready is what you need? You mention you need ajax... you're question really does not have enough information to give a viable answer.

Comment: when I add () I get Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ). I also tried ();

Comment: this got rid of that error but still not working    }); }());

Comment: @David it is added via bootstrap tabs..

Comment: Is your `tab-pane` added dynamically or is it there already on doc load?

Comment: @Igmars when I inspect the dom I see all the html in there before I even click the bootstrap tab which shows all the html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably be using the bootstrap event that is fired when a tab is shown and visible.

```
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function(event) {

     // Put your code

});
```

The selector is the button that is clicked to access your tab. This event will guarantee you that the tab is loaded and visible.

If you're not bothered about it being visible and want to access it earlier you can use the bootstrap event `show.bs.tab` instead that is fired as soon as you click on the tab.